# How to pass a dynamic value to a xml file?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

We were working with SOAP APIs in python. We need to dynamically pass the values in a request xml file.

`test.xml` file:

```xml
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <intA>3</intA>
            <intB>4</intB>
        </Add>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Python script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import lxml
url="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL"
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
xmlfile = open('test.xml','r')
body = xmlfile.read()


response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

We need to pass intA and intB dynamically from python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the format string method. You can specify the positional/keyword arguments in your xml file. While making the requests call, you can pass the values for those arguments.

Here is how your test.xml file should look like:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <intA>{first_number}</intA>
            <intB>{second_number}</intB>
        </Add>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

and in your Python script, you could load the xmlfile, and while making the posts requests, the arguments can be passed. Here is how:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL"
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml'}
xmlfile = open('test.xml', 'r')
body = xmlfile.read()

response = requests.post(url, data=body.format(first_number=1, second_number=4), headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```